# How to edit a jar file using java

Tags: java, jar

I kind of engaged in an automation process. There I have to modify  a jar file (just delete two files within )and copy it to a remote location. I tried using the solution given in [How to open a .jar file within Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851575/how-to-open-a-jar-file-within-java) But it didn't help (Honestly couldn't understand). Regards on a kind help. .

Comment: How did that not help? Jar files are just zip files, so opening them like any other zip file should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

if you have WinRar or WinZip software installed just right click on jar file and click extract here all the contains of jar file will be available to you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with an Ant script by using the unzip task : http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html

Answer (score 0):

Just do a little research could help a lot. You can open a .jar file using winRAR then decompile the .class file as stated here [How do I "decompile" Java class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files)

To recompile you can use 'javac' in command prompt provided you listed all the classpath necessary. [How to compile a .java file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279451/how-to-compile-a-java-file-in-java)

then you can overwrite the file in .jar